# Return data from the modal to the component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, service, modal-dialog

I have another problem with Angular. I don't know how to return data from a modal. A list of objects is displayed in my modal, then after clicking on an item in the list, I pass the object to the function. How to receive this object in another component?

**modal-geoname.component.html**

```
<ng-scrollbar #scrollable track="vertical" *ngIf="geonames.length > 0">
  <table class="table table-hover mb-0">
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let geoname of geonames; let i = index" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="selectGeoname(geoname)">
        <th scope="row">{{ i+1 }}</th>
        <td><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{ geoname.country | lowercase }} mr-2"></span>{{ geoname.country }}, {{ geoname.zipcode }} {{ geoname.place }}</td>
        <td>{{ geoname.admin }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-scrollbar>
```

**modal-geoname.component.ts**

```
export class ModalGeonameComponent implements OnInit {

  public geonames: Geoname[] = [];
  public selectedItem: Subject<boolean>;

  constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {}

  selectGeoname(geoname: Geoname) {
    this.selectedItem.next(geoname);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedItem = new Subject();
  }

}
```

**modal.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ModalService {

  bsModalRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(private bsModalService: BsModalService) {}

  // ... other open modal functions ...

  showGeonameModal(geonames: Geoname[]) {
    this.bsModalRef = this.bsModalService.show(ModalGeonameComponent, {
      initialState: { geonames },
      class: 'modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg',
      ignoreBackdropClick: true
    }).content.selectedItem.subscribe(selectedItem  => {
      console.log(selectedItem); 
      // I want to push selectedItem to itemList array in map-view.component.ts
    });
  }

}
```

**map-view.component.ts**

```
export class MapViewComponent {

  private searchCountry: string;
  private searchText: string;

  public itemList: Geoname[] = [];

  constructor(private geonameService: GeonameService, private modalService: ModalService) {}

  searchCity() {
    this.geonameService.getCity(this.searchText, this.searchCountry).subscribe((geonames) => {
      this.modalService.showGeonameModal(geonames);
      this.searchText = '';
    });
  }

}
```

I want to pass selectedItem to itemList. Please check the correctness of my code because I don't want to learn bad programming. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible in **BsModalService**:

> constructor(private modalService: BsModalService)

and then you can use by the following:

```
const modal = this.modalService.show(ModalGeonameComponent);


(<ModalGeonameComponent>modal.content).onClose.subscribe(result => {
      if(result) {
        this.result = Object.assign({}, result);
        .....
      }
    });
```

Comment: I can't do this, because I have modals in separate modal service.

Comment: @WojtekSzymczyk Then you have 2 options:

1. using another modal on the modal - which is possible via BsModalService but **not recommended** and not a good UX practice.

2. changing the way you are thinking of designing the page. Which I Recommend

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). If the 'ModalGeonameComponent' components it's a child component for 'MapViewComponent' you can pass data from child to parent using *Output property.* If those two components are at the same level (not parent - child) you can create a shared service between them (Using Observables) and pass the data from one component to another.  For more explications you can check this [tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

Comment: Modals are already in separate service and I want to use it. I don't know how to use Oberservables in my service.

Comment: You can check the last step of the above tutorial, section _Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service_.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. Now I can see my object in MapViewComponent under the variable geoname. But I have another problem.

The program is to behave like this: I choose an item from the list in the modal, then pass the object to MapViewComponent where I call the new function drawMap (object: Geoname) and close the modal. How to do it? How to close the modal and call the function?

My current code:

**modal-geoname.component.html**

```
<ng-scrollbar #scrollable track="vertical" [ngStyle]="{'min-height': setScrollbarHeight() }" *ngIf="geonames.length > 0">
  <table class="table table-hover mb-0">
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let geoname of geonames; let i = index" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="selectItem(geoname)">
        <th scope="row" style="width: 50px;">{{ i+1 }}</th>
        <td><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{ geoname.country | lowercase }} mr-2"></span>{{ geoname.country }}, {{ geoname.zipcode }} {{ geoname.place }}</td>
        <td>{{ geoname.admin }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-scrollbar>
```

**modal-geoname.component.ts**

```
export class ModalGeonameComponent {

  private geonames: Geoname[] = [];

  constructor(private bsModalRef: BsModalRef, private dataService: DataService) {}

  selectItem(geoname: Geoname) {
    this.dataService.selectGeoname(geoname);
  }

}
```

**data.service.ts**

```
export class DataService {

  private geonameSource = new BehaviorSubject<Geoname>('');
  currentGeoname = this.geonameSource.asObservable();

  selectGeoname(geoname: Geoname) {
    this.geonameSource.next(geoname);
  }

}
```

**modal.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ModalService {

  bsModalRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(private bsModalService: BsModalService) {}

  showGeonameModal(geonames: Geoname[]) {
    this.bsModalRef = this.bsModalService.show(ModalGeonameComponent, {
      initialState: { geonames },
      class: 'modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg',
      ignoreBackdropClick: true
    });
  }

}
```

**map-view.component.ts**

```
export class MapViewComponent implements OnInit {

  private searchCountry: string;
  private searchText: string;

  private geoname: Geoname;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private geonameService: GeonameService, private modalService: ModalService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.currentGeoname.subscribe(geoname => {
      this.geoname = geoname;
    });
  }

  searchCity() {
    this.geonameService.getCity(this.searchText, this.searchCountry).subscribe((geonames) => {
      this.modalService.showGeonameModal(geonames);
      this.searchText = '';
    });
  }

}
```